# parsing data in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have this code right here that I want to parse `data` from, it supposed to get the url that's located in the `url:` part, the code is :

```
var search = require('youtube-search');

var opts = {
  maxResults: 3,
  startIndex: 1
};

search('deadmau5', opts, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
     var title1 = results.indexOf("url:");
     var title2 = results.indexOf("&feature");
     var titl = results.substr(title1 + 7);
     var result = titl.substr(0, titl.indexOf("&feature"));
  console.log(result);
});
```

However I get this error:

```
    var titl = results.substr(title1 + 7);
                        ^
TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
],[object Object] has no method 'substr'
    at c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\iplogger.js:12:25
    at c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-search\index.js:42:9
    at Parser.<anonymous> (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-searc
h\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:255:20)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Object.saxParser.onclosetag (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\yout
ube-search\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:225:24)
    at emit (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-search\node_modules
\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:615:33)
    at emitNode (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-search\node_mod
ules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:620:3)
    at closeTag (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-search\node_mod
ules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:861:5)
    at Object.write (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-search\node
_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1293:29)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node
_modules\youtube-search\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:273:29)
    at Parser.parseString (c:\Users\karim_000\desktop\node_modules\youtube-searc
h\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:6:61)
```

I don't exactly know what I'm doing wrong, any insight or help? *Thanks in advance*

Comment: Are you just trying to get the first result's information?

Comment: Honestly, I was gonna figure out some way to individually parse all 3 to get them, but if you know of a better way, please tell me!

Comment: All three? You're getting 10 search results. You just want a string within `url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7ArUgxtlJs&feature=youtube_gdata',` like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7ArUgxtlJs`?

Comment: oops, yes all 3, and yes that's what I want to parse out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will log each substring of the URL which you are looking for so that you can further manipulate it.

```
var search = require('youtube-search');

var opts = {
  maxResults: 3,
  startIndex: 1
};

search('deadmau5', opts, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    console.log(result.url.substring(0, result.url.indexOf('&feature')));
  });
});
```

This yields:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9IBbMW2o_o
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O85-OXktNs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWb-zs1L8Ss
```

Answer (score 2):

results is an array of objects!

```
search('deadmau5', opts, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  results.forEach(function (result) {
    console.log(result.url);
  });
});
```

this code will iterate over your array and log the url-property of each object in your results-array!

and as Seth mentioned, you are getting more than 3 searchresults!

Answer (score 0):

Results is a Json Array and you cann't use string methods on it. Get the element that you want from Json and then use substr or any other method

Ex: first element's title in Json array can be found as
       var title= results[0]['title'];

I suggest you to read about **JSON**.